# How to initialize zohhak runner without the @runWith Annotation

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I want to use Zohhak but I must use a custom `@Runwith` runner.

I can't find a way to initialize it as it can be done with Mockito (`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()`)

Note: I'd rather not modify my custom runner...

Any idea?

Comment: Hi would have a look into ZohhakRunner source code, and  try to replicate somehow : https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/zohhak/api/runners/ZohhakRunner.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer: there is no built-in way to use zohhak without `@RunWith`

long answer:
Mockito's `initMocks` sets some fields, while junit's runner must provide all methods to be executed by junit. it's a very different problem. not sure if it's possible to do in other way (for example with rules). after all even when you use junit's native parameterized testing, you still have to use their own custom runner.

that's why zohhak's runner is small and delegate most of it's functionality. you can use that code to write your own runner. also, if you have any ideas for the improvements, feel free to make pull requests

if it helps you, junit allows you use multiple different runners in one file. you can have many inner classes, each with its own runner. but still: one class, one runner

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to use zohhak to avoid duplicated tests (8 identical tests). I can't dig that further so... well... I duplicated the code... I'll whip for that later...